# PHP Carrito de compras: mostrar mensaje 'echo' de "Venta Realizada" una sola vez

Tags: php, echo

estoy trabajando en una tienda en línea, cuando un cliente hace una compra debe de mostrarle una siguiente pantalla con el mensaje de "Venta Realizada", pero si compra más de un artículo, el mensaje se repite por la cantidad de productos que adquirió, este es el código que tengo:

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){
        
        $id = $item["id"];
        $sesion = $_SESSION['id'];
        $cantidad = $item["quantity"];
        $item_price = $item["quantity"]*$item["price"];
         $titulo = $item["title"];
        
        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO compra VALUES ('', '$sesion', '$id', '$titulo', '$cantidad', '$item_price', CURDATE(),CURTIME())";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    echo '

  <div class="layout" id="contenido">
    
    <div id="nombre-seccion"><h1>VENTA REALIZADA</h1></div>
        <div id="seccion">

    <p>Gracias por su compra.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

';
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para que el mensaje mostrada por 'echo' de "Venta Realizada" se muestre una sola vez?

Les agradezco la atención.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo mejor sería que lo pongas afuera del ciclo FOR, y hacer un array con el resultado de cada INSERT, si todo salio bien que salga el mensaje, algo asi:

```
$resultados = array();
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item) {
    $id = $item["id"];
    $sesion = $_SESSION['id'];
    $cantidad = $item["quantity"];
    $item_price = $item["quantity"]*$item["price"];
    $titulo = $item["title"];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO compra VALUES ('', '$sesion', '$id', '$titulo', '$cantidad', '$item_price', CURDATE(),CURTIME())";
    $resultados[] = $conn->query($sql); // Agregar el resultado al array: TRUE | FALSE
}

if (in_array(false, $resultados)) {
    // Uno de los items no se cargo
}
else {
    echo '<div class="layout" id="contenido">
        <div id="nombre-seccion"><h1>VENTA REALIZADA</h1></div>
        <div id="seccion">
        <p>Gracias por su compra.</p>
        </div>
        </div>';
}
```